# AttributeError: module 'rest_framework.serializers' has no attribute 'validationError'

Tags: python, django, validation, django-rest-framework

#### def validate_name(self,value):

```
    qs=contact.objects.filter(name=value)
    if qs.exists():
        raise serializers.validationError(f"{value} is already in contact name")
    return value
```

error:

```
in validate_name raise serializers.validationError(f"{value} is already in contact name")
AttributeError: module 'rest_framework.serializers' has no attribute 'validationError'
```

validate the name is already exists

Comment: I think the "v" is supposed to be capitalized.  `serializers.ValidationError`

Answer (score 0):

The `ValidationError` is a `class`, so it should begin with capitals.

```
serializers.ValidationError("Error text")
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/ from original docs

```
raise serializers.ValidationError({'field_name': 'your message'})
```

you can import from rest framework like this

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ValidationError
```